# Python "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python

I need some help. Trying to figure out what the issue is here.

```
        parse = json.loads(phoneget.text)
        phoneNUM = parse["tel"] # gets phone number
        phoneID = parse["idNum"] # gets id number
        print(sms_config.key) # ignore this
        print("Parse complete, here is your result:") # ignore this
        print("Phone:", parse["tel"]) # prints phone number
        print("ID:", parse["idNum"]) # prints id number
        print(phoneget) # prints url - ignore this

        # Slice the first number off (country code)
        phoneNUM = phoneNUM
        print(phoneNUM[1:])
```

```
Output: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

```
Desired output: 2345678900
```

Comment: What does `phoneNUM = phoneNUM` do? @oofer

Comment: You need to do ```print(str(phoneNUM)[1:])```. You cannot use slicing in integers

Comment: Storing a telephone number as an integer is a problem in the first place. It's a string that happens to consist of numerical digits, not an integer.

Comment: A remark in passing: country codes may have more than one digit. France is `33` and Ireland is `353`.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the error message is: TypeError which states the type of our error. A TypeError is raised when you try to perform an operation on a value that does not support that operation.
The second part of the error message is telling us the cause of the TypeError. Which means that we are treating an integer (which is a whole number), like a subscriptable object. Integers are not subscriptable objects. Only objects that contain other objects, like strings, lists, tuples, and dictionaries, are subscriptable i.e. we can use indexes to retrieve values from them.
So inorder to use integer value as a subscriptable object we need to type cast it to a string or any other subscriptable object.
Hence, use:
print(str(phoneNUM)[1:])

Answer (score 0):

The code `phoneNUM[1:]` is using the slicing/subcripting syntax to extract digits. However, **you cannot slice an integer**. That's why the error is `'int' object is not subscriptable`. Slicing only works on sequential data types like string or list. More info on slicing [here](https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-indexing-and-slicing-for-lists-tuples-strings-and-other-sequential-types/)

If you want to slice, you need to convert it to a string first

```py
phoneNUMstring = str(phoneNUM);
print(phoneNUMstring[1:]);
```